# Torando write_message parallel yielding

Tags: tornado

I just realised that `WebSocketHandler.write_message()` returns a Future. I have not been yielding this function in my functions before:

```
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def ff(self,msg):
      try:
         self.write_message(json.dumps(msg))
      except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
         pass
```

as opposed to:

```
   @tornado.gen.coroutine
   def ff(self,msg):
      try:
         yield self.write_message(json.dumps(msg))
      except tornado.websocket.WebSocketClosedError:
         pass
```

Why has this been working without an error? (running on Tornado 4.3)

Also for the design pattern:

```
for x in messages:
   yield self.write_message(x)
```

would it be advisable to replace with a parallel?:

```
yield [self.write_message(x) for x in messages]
```

**
Parallel WebSocketHandler wanting to send the same message to lots of websockets:

```
# WS is a list of WebSocketHandlers. 
yield [s.write_message(message) for s in WS]
```

Comment: The problem with the above parallel write is that if along the line there's a WebSocketClosedError Exception it is raised immediately causing the rest of the messages not to be written. Is there a way to currently suppress the exception?

Comment: I believe this can be solved with a coroutine wrap() function which catches the exception then yielding this instead of self.write_message(). However it would be really cool if there was a raise_error flag like that of httpClient.fetch()...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Future` returned by `write_message` is for flow control: it normally returns immediately, but when outgoing buffers reach a certain size it will wait until earlier messages have been sent. This slows the application down to match the network instead of allowing it to add more and more messages to the outgoing buffer.

These `Futures` should *not* be yielded in parallel: it defeats the purpose, and I don't think it would even work reliably: each call to `IOStream.write` invalidates the `Future` returned by the previous call.

If you're not writing a large volume of messages, you can ignore these `Futures`, but if you want to better control the amount of memory your application consumes, yield them one at a time.

Comment: Hi Ben, my above example wasn't right. I have a list of websocket handlers that i want to send the same message to. The rational for asking the question was I was wondering if kicking the write_message off in parallel for all these was quicker than looping through each websocket. See ** (updated) in original answer. I assume i still can't and shouldn't do this? Sorry if i'm not getting this

Comment: Ah. If they're different handlers, then yielding them in parallel won't break anything, but it may not be what you want: this will apply flow control to all writers based on the speed of the slowest recipient. (so if one client disconnects, messages to the others could be delayed until that client has timed out).

Comment: Hmm interesting. Ok you're right that wouldn't be what i want... So what's happening here, is that because the yield will wait until it resolves all the Futures and wait for the slowest to complete? Wouldn't this still happen with the normal loop scenario: for s in WS: s.write_message(message) ?

Comment: If you don't yield, then messages are just placed into a buffer, and this buffer is allowed to grow endlessly. So everyone is allowed to proceed, but memory usage will grow if you send at a rate higher than what the slowest client can sustain (or if you are unable to detect disconnected clients in a timely fashion)